# Trying To Create a J-Query Pop Up Redirect To Another Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Example Of One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUG6r.jpg) I am trying to create a popup which when the user clicks on the button inside the pop-up it takes them to a brand new pop-up. I can't seem to find the correct HTML script for it. So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas!

Comment: popup as in an alert box or a modal?

Comment: a modal which looks like

Comment: how did you get the first one open? Would be same approach

Comment: @PraveenK Use [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALSO.. you can do it with Customized modal `div` where no need for any other plugin also full style-customization the way you want and can include any type of content..  as in the following code: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eveta7dp/1/)

```js
$('.modal a').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});

$('.open-modal').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#overlay').show();
});
$('.modal-close').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay').hide();
    $('#modal1').show();
    $('#modal2').hide();
});

$('#modal2').hide();
$('#pg1btn1').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal2').show();
    $('#modal1').hide();
});
$('#pg2btn1').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal1').show();
    $('#modal2').hide();
});
$('#pg2btn2').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay').hide();
    $('#modal1').show();
    $('#modal2').hide();
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-family:verdana, sans-serif;
}
.modal {
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
    position:fixed;
    top:calc(50% - 100px);
    left:calc(50% - 200px);
    background-color:#EEE;
    border:2px #AAA solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    font-size:24px;
    padding:5px;
}
.modal-head {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:right;
}
.modal-head a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    margin-right:5px
}
.modal-action {
    display:block;
    background-color:#DDD;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 30px);
    margin-top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:2px #CCC solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.modal-action:hover {
    background-color:#BBB;
    border-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Crema crema chicory viennese sugar medium, rich mazagran americano aftertaste cinnamon rich. Filter, frappuccino that decaffeinated siphon caffeine so sit dripper. French press shop carajillo cappuccino mocha medium white lungo.</div>
<div><a href="" class="open-modal">Activate Modal</a>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-head"><a href="" class="modal-close">x</a>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><strong>Page ONE: </strong>Ristretto spoon galão bar, lungo siphon whipped variety seasonal half and half. Dripper plunger pot saucer crema extraction filter arabica. <a href="" id="pg1btn1" class="modal-action">Next</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-head"><a href="" class="modal-close">x</a>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><strong>Page TWO: </strong>Roast, steamed, robust, chicory qui kopi-luwak, cappuccino, roast half and half cappuccino aromatic variety. Rich a mazagran qui cup barista chicory. <a href="" id="pg2btn1" class="modal-action" style="left:100px">Prev</a><a href="" id="pg2btn2" class="modal-action" style="left:250px;border-color:red;color:red;">Close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! I am going to use this but add some extra styling.

Answer (score 2):

With the Foundation and nested modals, this is possible.

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="#" data-reveal-id="firstModal" class="radius button">Example Modal&hellip;</a>

<!-- Reveal Modals begin -->
<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>This is a modal.</h2>
  <p>Reveal makes these very easy to summon and dismiss. The close button is simply an anchor with a unicode character icon and a class of <code>close-reveal-modal</code>. Clicking anywhere outside the modal will also dismiss it.</p>
  <p>Finally, if your modal summons another Reveal modal, the plugin will handle that for you gracefully.</p>
  <p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal" class="secondary button">Second Modal...</a></p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="secondModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2>This is a second modal.</h2>
  <p>See? It just slides into place after the other first modal. Very handy when you need subsequent dialogs, or when a modal option impacts or requires another decision.</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOdPqK**

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH! FOR THE HELP!

Comment: @PraveenK You are welcome buddy... Sorry had to struggle a lot to get this work done. `:)`

Comment: I used the code above. But when i try to click on Example Modal... Nothing Happens

Comment: @PraveenK Did you check the code here?

Comment: @PraveenK Does that work here, as expected?

Comment: Soz to keep you up so late! I need to go so ill check again tomorow! Ty For The Help!

Comment: @PraveenK Any time da... We both share same names. So message me and a reply is guaranteed. `:)`

Comment: Just wondering if you could send the scripts as a zip file so that I could download it

Comment: @PraveenK Sure buddy. Will try.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar

Comment: Got anything @PraveenKumar

Comment: I have used exactly the same code above but nothing happens when i click on the button..

Comment: @PraveenK Hi da... Can you please create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co)?

Comment: Its totally fine I used the answer below!